# Where can I learn more about "approximate isometries"?

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

Let $Y$ and $X$ denote metric spaces and $f : Y \leftarrow X$ denote a function.

> **Definition 0.** Call $f$ an *approximate isometry* iff for all $x \in X,$ we have that for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0},$ there
>   exists $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that for all $x'$ within
>   distance $\delta$ from $x$, we have that
>   $$\|d_Y(f(x),f(x'))-d_X(x,x')\|<\varepsilon.$$

(This is my own terminology.)

So intuitively, an approximate isometry is a function that can be made to look as close to being an isometry as you wish by looking at a sufficiently "small" subset of the domain. There's also a stronger notion:

> **Definition 1.** Call $f$ a *uniformly approximate isometry* iff for all $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0},$ there exists $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that for all $x,x' \in X$ within distance $\delta$ from each other, we have that $$\|d_Y(f(x),f(x'))-d_X(x,x')\|<\varepsilon.$$

Such functions seem to be pretty common. For example, the function that "wraps" $\mathbb{R}^2$ around a cylinder seems to be a uniformly approximate isometry, as far as I can tell.

> **Question.** Where can I learn more about these two concepts?

Comment: Any particular reason for writing $f \colon Y \leftarrow X$?

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi, I always write the arrow backwards, to make the composition law easier: $$\frac{g : Z \leftarrow Y, \quad f:Y \leftarrow X}{g \circ f : Z \leftarrow X}$$

Comment: A function is an approximate isometry if and only if it is continuous...

Comment: My vote for a good name: 'uniform parasometry'.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I could be wrong, but I think you're mistaken. To get mere continuity, we would replace $\|d_Y(f(x),f(x'))-d_X(x,x')\|<\varepsilon$ with $d_Y(f(x),f(x'))<\varepsilon$. Unless you can prove that these are equivalent?

Comment: @goblin: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f$ is an approximate isometry if and only if it is continuous. Proof: Given a small number $a$, another number $b$ is small if and only if $b$ is close to $a$. In detail:

Suppose $f$ is an approximate isometry, $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ as in the definition of partial isometry. Since any smaller $\delta$ also works, we can assume $\delta<\epsilon$. Now if $d(x.x')<\delta$ the triangle inequality shows that $$d(f(x),f(x'))\le d(x,x')+|d(f(x),f(x'))+d(x,x')|\le d(x,x')+\epsilon<2\epsilon.$$

Suppose $f$ is continuous, $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ so $\delta<\epsilon$ and $d(x,x')<\delta$ implies $d(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon$. If $d(x,x')<\delta$ the triangle inequality shows $$|d((f(x),f(x'))-d(x,x')|\le d(f(x),f(x'))+d(x,x')<2\epsilon.$$

Comment: Hmmm you seem to be right. Let me ponder it a bit more.

Comment: I think I can see where my definitions fall down: they deal with absolute error, as opposed to "relative error." In short, I need to divide by something somewhere in order to get an interesting concept.

Comment: The concept of approximate isometry as it stands is already very interesting! Just not all that new... heh.